# What's the equivalent to ownPubKey in the newer version of Plutus?

Tags: plutus, plutus-pioneer-program

In lesson 5 that they use a built in function called `ownPubKey` to access the wallet pubKey in the transaction on the plutus playground.

This function seems to be non-existent in the newer versions of plutus what is a good replacement for this?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ownPaymentPubKeyHash` here is [the source code](https://github.com/input-output-hk/plutus-apps/blob/5ffdb6362b9ba3e7095beccde56df0280abf12d0/plutus-contract/src/Plutus/Contract/Request.hs#L769).

It will work by just replacing `ownPubKeyHash` with `ownPaymentPubKeyHash` and return type `PubKeyHash` to `PaymentPubKeyHash`.

Comment: Here is: [How to reference material written by others](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/referencing)

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, I haven't found one either. If you need the PubKey to compute the hash you can use `ownPaymentPubKeyHash`